# SVG animation in styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, styled-components

I have different svgs in the form of

```
<svg class="logo">
 <path .../>
 <path .../>
 ...
</svg>
```

I would like to animate the individual paths. In vanilla JS I would do something like

```
const logo = document.querySelectorAll('.logo path');

for (let i = 0; i < logo.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${i}: ${logo[i].getTotalLength()}`);
}
```

to find the individual paths' lengths manually, and then do the animation in css path by path like so

```
...
.logo path:nth-child(2) {
  stroke-dasharray: ...;
  stroke-dashoffset: ...;
  animation: anim 2s ease-in-out forwards;
}
.logo path:nth-child(3) {
  stroke-dasharray: ...;
  stroke-dashoffset: ...;
  animation: anim 2s ease-in-out forwards 0.2s;
}
...
@keyframes anim {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

I am using styled components in my React project, and I would like to make the above logic in accordance with the overall project style, in other words, using styled components. What's the most efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using web animations api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API).
So the animations can be set via JS, so you can use your supplied JS code to calculate the length and store them in variables. You then use those variables in the web animations api so you don't have to calculate and input then manually.